# Why $\,p\, (p^{-1}\!\bmod q) + q\,(q^{-1}\!\bmod p) = pq + 1?$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This is going to sound like a stupid question, but I cannot understand how I get this result (I understand why, but it looks like there is no relation). For $p, q$ primes why do we have this?

$$p\, (p^{-1}\!\bmod q) + q\,(q^{-1}\!\bmod p) = pq + 1$$

I don't see the relation between the left and right side, but still it works.

Comment: can you explain more about your expression?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is ill-defined, you work either modulo $p$ or modulo $q$.

Comment: In this context, I believe that $p^{-1}\pmod q$ represents the integer which is congruent to $p^{-1}$ mod $q$ between $\{0,\cdots,q-1\}$ but treated as an integer, not as an element of $\mathbb{Z}/q$.

Comment: It's seems to me like your post is related to the Chinese remainder theorem. That seems worth mentioning

Comment: It doesn't look like modular arithmetic. If by "mod" you mean the reminder operation: a mod b := l, where $a = b k + l$ and $0 \le l < b$, then just put it into the expression.

Comment: yes it is related to CRT, the special case when $y = 1 \mod p$ and $y = 1 \mod q$ then $y = 1 \mod pq$, but this is the equation itself that I wrote.

Comment: anyone? I still can't get it... Maybe garner's way is clearer ( http://e-maxx-eng.github.io/algebra/chinese-remainder-theorem.html )

Comment: **Bezout** form: $\,\gcd(a,b)\!=\!1\!\iff\! a(a^{-1}\!\bmod b)-b(-b^{-1}\!\bmod a) = 1\ \ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it is tacitly assumed that $p\ne q$.

I'm interpreting $\ p^{-1}\>{\rm mod}\>  q$ as the unique $x\in[1\>..\>q-1]$ with $xp=1\>{\rm mod}\>  q$, and similarly $\ q^{-1}\>{\rm mod}\> p$ as the unique $y\in[1\>..\>p-1]$ with $yq=1\>{\rm mod}\>  p$. If $x$ and $y$ are determined in this way the number $n:=xp+yq$ satisfies $$ n\leq 2pq-p-q$$
and
$$n=1\ {\rm mod}\>  p,\qquad n=1\ {\rm mod}\>  q\ .\tag{2}$$
The number $n':=pq+1$ satisfies $(2)$. On the other hand, by the Chinese remainder theorem there can be no other such number in the interval $[\,pq,\> 2pq-p-q\,]$. It follows that $n=n'$.

If you want to avoid the CRT you can argue as follows: As ${\rm gcd}(p,q)=1$ there are $x$, $y\in{\mathbb Z}$ with $$xp-yq=1\ .$$
After adding a suitable $kq$ to $x$, and at the same time $kp$ to $y$ we may assume $x\in[1\>..\>q-1]$. It follows that
$$yq=xp-1\in[p-1\>..\>pq-p-1]\ ,$$
which then implies $y\in[1\>..\>p-1]$. It follows that $y':=p-y\in[1\>..\>p-1]$ as well, and we now have
$$xp+y'q=xp+(p-y)q=pq+1\ ,$$
which is the claimed formula.

Comment: I think the upper bound in (1) is $2pq - (p + q)$, also according to the CRT a unique $n$ exists in $[[0, pq]]$, not in the bounds of (1) (unless I'm missing something?)

Comment: @David天宇Wong: Thank you for notifying the slip.

Comment: **Bezout** form: $\,\gcd(a,b)\!=\!1\!\iff\! a(a^{-1}\!\bmod b)-b(-b^{-1}\!\bmod a) = 1\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

First, let's clarify the question, since one of the commenters was confused:
By
$$p \cdot (p^{-1} \mod q)$$ the question means to find $ p^{-1}\mod q$, transform that into the unique integer $\bar{p} \in \Bbb{N} : \bar{p} \equiv p^{-1}\mod q \wedge 0\leq \bar{p} < q$, and then multiply, in the ordinary field of integers,
$p\cdot \bar{p}$.

With that understanding in place, here is your proof that $s = p \cdot (p^{-1} \mod q) + q \cdot (q^{-1} \mod p) = pq+1$ assuming $p,q$ prime:

Lemma 1: $p \cdot (p^{-1} \mod q) \equiv 1 \mod q$.  Proof: This is just the definition of the inverse, mod $q$.

Corollary 2: $s \equiv 1 \mod q$.  Proof: $s =  p \cdot (p^{-1} \mod q) + qk$ where $k$ is some integer (which happens to be $(q^{-1} \mod p)$) so $s  \equiv 1 + 0 \mod q$.

Corollary 3: $s \equiv 1 \mod p$. This is the same statement as corollary 2, exchanging $p$ and $q$.

Lemma 4:  $s \equiv 1 \mod (pq)$.  This is so by corollaries 2 and 3, along with the statement that $p$ and $p$ are coprime.

Lemma 5: $s > 1$.  Proof: each of the terms in $s$ is a positive integer, so $s \geq 1+1$.

Lemma 6: $p \cdot (p^{-1} \mod q) < pq$ and $q \cdot (q^{-1} \mod p) < qp$. Proof: $p^{-1} \mod q < q$; multiply both sides of that relation by $p$. Similarly for the assertion about $q \cdot (q^{-1} \mod p)$.

Corollary 7: $s = p \cdot (p^{-1} \mod q) + q \cdot (q^{-1} \mod p) < 2pq$.

Theorem: $s=pq+1$. Proof: by lemma 5 and corollary 7, $1 < s < pq$.  By lemma 4, $s = kpq + 1$ for some integer $k$.  The unique value of the form $kpq + 1$ between $1$ and $2pq$ is $pq+1$.

Q.E.D.